# Ansible: group values on same line with common key

Tags: ansible

I'm  struggling to group some common values on a same line, with ansible.
I have the vg name and disks on each line, as follows:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "vg01  /dev/xvdk",
        "vg01 /dev/xvdj",
        "vg02  /dev/xvdi",
        "vg02  /dev/xvdh",
        "vg03  /dev/xvdg",
        "vg03  /dev/xvdf"
    ]
}
```

Now, I want the vg with all it's disks, on one same line, one per vg, as below:

```
"vg01 /dev/xvdk, /dev/xvdj",
"vg02 /dev/xvdi, /dev/xvdh",
"vg03 /dev/xvdg, /dev/xvdf",
```

Still not able to achieve this; Can someone help, please?
Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: Hi Zeitounator ; Thanks for your interest; I was trying to add a set_fact with a variable, as proposed in the end of this post: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/208838/how-would-i-register-a-dynamically-named-variable-in-an-ansible-task , for each vg, But I got lost completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a list of dictionaries. For example, given the data is stored in the variable *disks*

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        l1: "{{ l1|default([]) + [{'dsk': item.split(' ')|first,
                                   'dev': item.split(' ')|last}] }}"
      loop: "{{ disks }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  l1:
  - dev: /dev/xvdk
    dsk: vg01
  - dev: /dev/xvdj
    dsk: vg01
  - dev: /dev/xvdi
    dsk: vg02
  - dev: /dev/xvdh
    dsk: vg02
  - dev: /dev/xvdg
    dsk: vg03
  - dev: /dev/xvdf
    dsk: vg03
```

Use *groupby* filter and format the lines in the loop, for example

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.0 }} {{ item.1|flatten|map(attribute='dev')|join(', ') }}"
      loop: "{{ l1|groupby('dsk') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: vg01 /dev/xvdk, /dev/xvdj
  msg: vg02 /dev/xvdi, /dev/xvdh
  msg: vg03 /dev/xvdg, /dev/xvdf
```

---

A more robust option, using *regex_replace/from_yaml*, might be able to handle some malformed data where simple *split/first/last* would fail e.g.

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        l1: "{{ l1|default([]) + [item.0|combine(item.1)] }}"
      with_together:
        - "{{ disks|map('regex_replace', '^(.*?) (.*)$', 'dsk: \\1')|
                    map('from_yaml')|list }}"
        - "{{ disks|map('regex_replace', '^(.*?) (.*)$', 'dev: \\2')|
                    map('from_yaml')|list }}"
```

Comment: Thanks Vladimir! Tested, and exactly what I wanted; Nice! I'm happy with 1st suggestion.